# Data Partition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, partitioning, zoo

I am looking for a *robust* way to partition a dataset without using the `sample()` function, and hope to get some feedback.

As a matter of fact, I'd ideally like to get rid of the of `random` property inherent to the usage of `sample()`

```
samp<-data.frame(qldat)   # convert zoo time-series object to data.frame
ind <- sample(2,nrow(samp),replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8,0.2))  # splitting
#data series between training and test sets
tsamp<- samp[ind==1,]  # training dataset
vsamp<- samp[ind==2,]  # test set
```

Following some researches, I've figured out that `subset()` could have helped, but it could involve a bit of `hard-coding`the dataset. By *hard-coding* I mean for a **80:20 split(%)** using  `nrow(samp)`, It's possible to subset the data from `row=1` to `row= 0.8 * nrow(samp)` for instance, acknowledging that it might not be a very efficient solution.

I've also tried `createDataPartition()`, but it did not match my expectation since `samp` does not hold any `categorical data` on which I could rely on for the split (e.g `createDataPartition(y=samp$categoricaldata,p=0.8, list=FALSE`)

**PS**: What I like in `ind<-` is the inclusion of `prob=c(0.8,0.2)`, thus the slice is sorted out automatically. Hence any similar idea without randomly splitting `tsamp` && `vsamp` would be very appreciated.

Best,

Comment: If not random, how do you want to determine which part of the data is training and test? Do you always want to do this by the sequence in which rows appear in the data? What happens if a 'clear' split cannot be done (like probs of 0.2 and 0.8 and 101 observations).

Comment: @Heroka: by using `nrow()`. If a particular column is indexed from let's say `[1:10]` then consider the first split from `[round(1*80%):8]` for `tsamp`. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
n <- nrow(samp)
train_i <- 1:round(0.8*n)
test_i <- round(0.8*n+1):n
train <- samp[train_i,]
test <- samp[test_i,]
```

Comment: Thanks, as you've definitely got my point. Your suggestion does work and I will accept it as answer, although -as indicated in the thread- I would not like to hard-code somehow the dataset using `(0.8* n)` for instance. Maybe there is no other alternative...

Comment: do you want the split proportions to be random or what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: so far, I'm happy with the static weights, but just thought there could be a different way to replicate it within a single statement like in `ind<-`.

Comment: Can you describe a setting in which the above approach doesnt work?

Comment: "All roads lead[ing] to rome", your approach works, no worries. Mine edited in the post via `<-ind` works too, and I had a slight preference towards the inclusion of the weight vector. Unfortunately and as expected, my training and test sets were randomly populated due to `sample()` and I had been looking for a similar syntax (if existing) without `sample()`. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Won't this include one sample in both sets?

Comment: @Heroka: see `tsamp<-` && `vsamp` as complements.